# Diverging losses in PPO + ICM using LSTM

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have tried to implement Proximal Policy Optimization with Intrinsic Curiosity Rewards for statefull LSTM neural network.

Losses in both PPO and ICM are diverging and I would like to find out if its bug in code or badly selected hyperparameters.

### Code (where some wrong implementation could be):

- In ICM model I use first layer LSTM too to match input dimensions.
- In ICM whole dataset is propagated at once, with zeros as initial hidden(resultin tensors are different, than they would be if I propagated only 1 state or batch and re-use hidden cells)
- In PPO advantage and discount reward processing the dataset is propagated one by one and hidden cells are re-used (exact opposite than in ICM because here it uses same model for selecting actions and this approach is "real-time-like")
- In PPO training model is trained on batches with re-use of hidden cells

I have used https://github.com/adik993/ppo-pytorch as default code and reworked it to run on my environment and use LSTM

I may provide code samples later if specifically requested due to large amount of rows

### Hyperparameters:

```py
def __init_curiosity(self):
        curiosity_factory=ICM.factory(MlpICMModel.factory(), policy_weight=1,
                                      reward_scale=0.1, weight=0.2,
                                      intrinsic_reward_integration=0.01,
                                      reporter=self.reporter)
        self.curiosity = curiosity_factory.create(self.state_converter,
                                                  self.action_converter)
        self.curiosity.to(self.device, torch.float32)
        self.reward_normalizer = StandardNormalizer()
    
def __init_PPO_trainer(self):
        self.PPO_trainer = PPO(agent = self,
                               reward = GeneralizedRewardEstimation(gamma=0.99, lam=0.95),
                               advantage = GeneralizedAdvantageEstimation(gamma=0.99, lam=0.95),
                               learning_rate = 1e-3,
                               clip_range = 0.3,
                               v_clip_range = 0.3,
                               c_entropy = 1e-2,
                               c_value = 0.5,
                               n_mini_batches = 32,
                               n_optimization_epochs = 10,                               
                               clip_grad_norm = 0.5)
        self.PPO_trainer.to(self.device, torch.float32)
```

### Training graphs:

(Notice large numbers on y axis)

[image: '']

[image: '']

[image: '']

[image: '']

[image: '']

[image: '']

---

### UPDATE

For now I have reworked LSTM processing to use batches and hidden memory on all places (for both main model and ICM), but the problem is still present. I have traced it to output from ICM's model, here the output diverges mainly in `action_hat` tensor.

Comment: Does your task have time series? Otherwise LSTM may be harmful. There was a guy trying to solve a very basic RL task (cart pole I guess) with LSTM and it was also diverging, while it was working with a simple NN.

Comment: Same here, with simple NN it converges. Anyway yes, I'm playing with stock market technical-analysis indicators which are time dependent

Comment: Then it's probably something with the LSTM, but I never used any so I cannot help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... In main model I use softmax for eval runs and log_softmax for training in output layer and according to PyTorch docs the [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) uses log_softmax inside, so as advised I used [NLLLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#nllloss) but forthe computation of ICM model loss which does not have softmax fnc in output layer! So **switching back to** [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) (which was originaly in reference code) solved ICM loss divergence.